# Need help with setting up MS-SQL on EC2

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have a large MS-SQL database that i need to send to the aws cloud.
The issue is how do i persist my sql data and how to setup MS-SQL cluster using windows AMI.

The real issue is that for replication i need to use the private ip's of the instances. However, these ip's are always dynamic and will change on server launch.

Any ideas on how i can get rid of this problem.

I really appreciate  your help

Best Regards
Hareem Haque

Answer (score 0):

Use [Elastic Block Store](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) (EBS) volumes to persist your SQL data.

The private IP address won't change after a server restart; are you wondering how to get the IP address of a new instance ?  If so, you'll probably have to do some scripting and use the [EC2 API tools](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=351&categoryID=251) to get the IP address of each new instance.  Post a comment if I've got the wrong end of the stick and I'll try to help more.